# Migrating from wordpress to django without losing pagerank

Tags: django, wordpress, seo

I have got a blog in wordpress (www.ashwinm.com) which i am looking to migrate to django as i am very much impressed with it. Is there any way so that i can migrate to django without losing my current pagerank (which is 3)?

- I don't mind losing all current contents of this blog as it is too old.

Comment: You don't mind losing the content? It's the content the reason you have your current page rank?

Comment: i know,but it has become obsolete.also i don't have that type of enthusiasm to update regularly anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a high pagerank, that is probably because you have content and the content is linked to by other people.  You should try to keep that content in some form (it doesn't have to be exactly the same form), or at least ensure that every URL that is being linked to redirects to something useful.  No one who follows a previously valid link to your website should get a 404.

Your content and your inbound links together are responsible for your pagerank, so if you let both die then you're back at square one, regardless of what web application framework you are using.

If I were doing it I would probably set up the new blog with Django and import the data manually.  Or, if there is simply way too much data, I could move the Wordpress server to be served from a directory such as /archive and instruct my webserver to 301 redirect all of the old Wordpress blog entry URLs to the new directory.  You would have to continue to maintain the Wordpress installation to some degree, but you would be 100% certain to keep all of your pagerank.

Comment: can u please explain the process,after i move all my current  files in the public folder of my server to a single directory say /archive how do i set up 301 redirect,what about robot.txt file?

Comment: I don't think I have enough info on your setup to conclusively tell you how to do this, but in general it would be better to handle the 301 redirect at the webserver level and not at the application level (django in this case).  You can do that by modifying your server configuration and either enumerating all of the valid pages on your current site or using some kind of general rule, the specific of which depends on your application.

Answer (score 5):

You could take a look at something like [django-wordpress](https://github.com/sunlightlabs/django-wordpress). That would allow you to keep your current content in the existing wordpress DB (read-only) and continue to develop other portions of the site with Django.